# Join distinct FASTA files using python and Biopython

Tags: python, biopython, fasta

I have to create a software that pick multi fasta files and create another with all the sequences. For that I have done the following code:

```
import sys,random
from Bio import SeqIO
from Bio.Seq import Seq
from Bio.SeqRecord import SeqRecord
from Bio import AlignIO

# Use: python join_fasta.py infile1.fasta infile2.fasta outfile.fasta


infile1 = sys.argv[1]                                #Name of the input file
seq1 = list(SeqIO.parse(infile1,"fasta"))             #Create a list with all the sequence records
print "Input the first fasta file = ", infile1

infile2 = sys.argv[2]                                #Name of the input file
seq2 = list(SeqIO.parse(infile2,"fasta"))             #Create a list with all the sequence records
print "Input the second fasta file = ", infile2

totseq1 = len(seq1)                                   #Total number of sequences in the input file
print "Number of sequences in the first file = ", totseq1

totseq2 = len(seq2)                                   #Total number of sequences in the input file
print "Number of sequences in the first file = ", totseq2

outfile = sys.argv[3]                               #Name of the output file
print "Output fasta file = ", outfile

totseq3 = len(seq1) + len(seq2)                                   #Total number of sequences in the output file
print "Number of sequences in the concatenated file = ", totseq3

output = [infile1, infile2]




SeqIO.write(output, outfile, "fasta") 

exit()
```

It return a error:

```
Input the first fasta file =  ITS.fasta
Input the second fasta file =  banco_de_dados_ITS.fasta
Number of sequences in the first file =  114
Number of sequences in the first file =  20
Output fasta file =  ITS_combined.fasta
Number of sequences in the concatenated file =  134
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/phdias/Documents/Softwares_PH/join_fasta.py", line 35, in <module>
    SeqIO.write(output, outfile, "fasta") 
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Bio/SeqIO/__init__.py", line 535, in write
    fp.write(format_function(record))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Bio/SeqIO/FastaIO.py", line 345, in as_fasta
    id = _clean(record.id)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'id'
```

I try a lot to resolve this problem without success

The code was rewritten:

```
import sys,random
from Bio import SeqIO
from Bio.Seq import Seq
from Bio.SeqRecord import SeqRecord
from Bio import AlignIO

# Use: python join_fasta.py infile1.fasta infile2.fasta outfile.fasta


infile1 = sys.argv[1]                                #Name of the input file
seq1 = list(SeqIO.parse(infile1,"fasta"))             #Create a list with all the sequence records
print "Input the first fasta file = ", infile1

infile2 = sys.argv[2]                                #Name of the input file
seq2 = list(SeqIO.parse(infile2,"fasta"))             #Create a list with all the sequence records
print "Input the second fasta file = ", infile2

totseq1 = len(seq1)                                   #Total number of sequences in the input file
print "Number of sequences in the first file = ", totseq1

totseq2 = len(seq2)                                   #Total number of sequences in the input file
print "Number of sequences in the second file = ", totseq2

outfile = sys.argv[3]                               #Name of the output file
print "Output fasta file = ", outfile

totseq3 = len(seq1) + len(seq2)                                   #Total number of sequences in the output file
print "Number of sequences in the concatenated file = ", totseq3

from itertools import chain
output = list(chain(seq1, seq2))


SeqIO.write(output, outfile, "fasta") 

exit()
```

And now it not find the second file, the output file just contains the sequences from the first one:

```
Input the first fasta file =  ITS.fasta
Input the second fasta file =  banco_de_dados_ITS.fasta
Number of sequences in the first file =  114
Number of sequences in the second file =  0
Output fasta file =  its_c.fasta
Number of sequences in the concatenated file =  114
```

Comment: Seems like there are no modifications in how you are reading the second file. Did you check if the content of the second file has changed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is here:

```py
output = [infile1, infile2]
```

You are using the file paths which are of type `str` instead of using `seq1` and `seq2`, and also you need to concatenate them to a single sequence, like that:

```py
from itertools import chain
output = chain(seq1, seq2)
```

This way `output` is a generator of `SeqRecord` items from both `seq1` and `seq2`

Comment: Worked but just give me the sequences from the first file:  'Input the first fasta file =  ITS.fasta
Input the second fasta file =  banco_de_dados_ITS.fasta
Number of sequences in the first file =  114
Number of sequences in the second file =  0
Output fasta file =  ITS_combined.fasta
Number of sequences in the concatenated file =  114'

Comment: I need to see the modifications you made, maybe update the code in the question (under an Edit part) so it will be much more clear what the problem might be.

Answer (score 1):

While BioPython is a great tool, things will be easier if you used pandas.

```
import pandas as pd

def fasta_reader(file):
    fasta_df = pd.read_csv(file, sep='>', lineterminator='>', header=None)
    fasta_df[['Accession', 'Sequence']] = fasta_df[0].str.split('\n', 1, \
                                        expand=True)
    fasta_df.drop(0, axis=1, inplace=True)
    fasta_df['Sequence'] = fasta_df['Sequence'].replace('\n', '', regex=True)
    return fasta_df
```

If your fasta files are named as `test1.fa`, `test2.fa`, you can then use `pd.concat` to join.

```
df = pd.concat(fasta_reader(i) for i in ['test1.fa', 'test2.fa'])
```

Then you can also export the concatenated file as a fasta. But first you need to add `>` in front of accessions.

```
# Exporting to fa
# adding '>' for accessions
df['Accession'] = '>' + df['Accession']
df.to_csv('combined.fa', sep='\n', index=None, header=None)
```